# Permission warning in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite

I am working on one project for a client who has several multisite installed in wordpress. Site is working well but I am experiencing a warning message when I click the Video link in home page.The message is shown below:

[rocktron Uk](http://www.rktron.devstars.net/uk/videos/)

```
Warning: file_put_contents(cache/ecd2071956f5730430b8b710d168a85d.spc) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/default/rktron.devstars.net/user/htdocs/simplepie.inc on line 8671
Warning: cache is not writeable. Make sure you've set the correct relative or absolute path, and that the location is server-writable. in /home/default/rktron.devstars.net/user/htdocs/simplepie.inc on line 1780
```

The code is defined in videos-page.php which is shown below:

```
// YouTube RSS URL via FeedBurner: http://feeds.feedburner.com/rocktron
require_once(getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT"). '/simplepie.inc');
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url(array('http://feeds.feedburner.com/rocktron'));
$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location('cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(1800);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
```

Everything works , video page shown, videos also play but warning message shown on top of the video page.

Any clue to solve this mystery will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any specific reason to use externally loaded SimplePie?

WordPress comes with SimplePie bundled and has wrappers that properly integrate and set up caching for it. See [`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) in Codex.

Comment: Hey Rarst,Thank you for your comments. Well I am actually modifying existing code of someone who just left the company! I have no idea why he used simplepie to be honest with you. The link you provided is quite helpful. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states the cache is not writeable. That means you have to go check and change the permissions on the folder that is gives you in the error message.

First off, have a look at the file in /home/default/rktron.devstars.net/user/htdocs/simplepie.inc on line 1780. What does it say? What folder is it looking for?

This is all to do with simplepie on your server. It's actually noting multisite-specific.

Comment: Hi Andrea, Thanks for your comment. I will definitely have a look on that.